# Ловлю вылет приложения при вызове notifyItemChanged();

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, broadcast-receiver

RAdapter.class - в методе onBindViewHolder ловлю броадкасты для обновления элементов в блоке RecyclerView, но при множественных обновлениях UI происходит вылет приложения, при том в логах ничего нет они просто обрываются. Если убираю notifyItemChanged(); все отрабатывает без ошибок броадкасты прилетают, но с notifyItemChanged(); примерно после ста обновлений происходит вылет. Непонимаю в чем дело, возможно кто-то сталкивался, буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final RAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int i) {
       
     broadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(PARAM_STATUS, 0);
        
                        if (status == 1) {
                            int result = intent.getIntExtra("RESULT", 0);
                            progress.set(position, result);
                            notifyItemChanged(position);
                        }
        
        }
                };
    }
```

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, а почему вы переменную status типа int сравниваете со стройкой?

Comment: @МихаилРебров ой точно) дабы сократить пример редактировал в браузере, не заметил)

Comment: Попробуйте убрать инициализацию каждый раз int status. Вынесите её в общую часть. Или избавьтесь.. >> if (intent.getIntExtra(PARAM_STATUS, 0) == 1). Тоже самое ниже по коду

Comment: @ArtyMorris пробовал полностью избавится от этих переменных, результат один, вылет. Пока временно решил проблему сократив частоту вызова notifyItemChanged(); , не уверен, но думаю ошибка была в том что UI не успевал обновиться а броадкаст в этот момент снова вызывал notifyItemChanged();

Comment: Попробуйте тогда обновление вынести отдельно с частотой  в секунду или полсекунды. А интент обрабатывать по мере поступления

Comment: @ArtyMorris так и сделал, это частично помогло. Но, теперь проблема в повторном запуске т.е. цикл отрабатывает  полностью отсылая result в броадкаст приемник, тригер if (status == 1) срабатывает только по мере обновления значения. При повторном запуске через пару циклов краш. Конспектирую notifyItemChanged(); все идеально. LOG ничего не дает, все переменные отрабатывают идеально.